# validating javascript with count

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I am having trouble figuring out my Javascript code. I'm still learning all of this (im not the best at it). Theres a couple things I cant get to work. When I submit this form, it will not highlight what hasn't been answered (all it does is just reset upon submission). Also I cant figure out on how to count the number or correct answers and display them. Heres my code, if anyone could help me that would be great. UPDATED CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>3 Questions</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" id="form1" onsubmit="return FormValidation()";>
<div class="q1">
    1) Spell Java?<br/>
    <input type="text" id="q1" name="name"/><br/>
</div>
<div class="q2">
    2) What does .org mean?<br/>
    <input type="radio" id="network" name="net"/>Network
    <input type="radio" id="organ" name="org"/>Organization
</div><br/><br/>
<div class="q3">
    3) Who won the last Superbowl?<br/>
    <select name="team">
        <option value="sea" id="hawks" name="sea">Seattle Seahawks</option>
        <option value="broncos" id="denver" name="broncos">Denver Broncos</option>
    </select>
</div><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function FormValidation(){

if document.getElementById(q1).style.borderColor = "red";


if document.getElementById(denver).style.borderColor = "red";
else if document.getElementById(hawks).style.borderColor = "green";
return false

if document.getElementById(network).style.borderColor = "red";
else if document.getElementById(organ).style.borderColor = "green";
return false

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The syntax of your `if` statements isn't valid. Aren't you getting syntax error messages in the console?

Comment: no, just "refreshes" the page

Comment: You still have incorrect `if` statement syntax. It's `if (condition) { true-body } else { false-body }`

Comment: You also need to put quotes around strings like `denver` and `hawks`. You need to learn basic Javascript syntax before you can hope to write an application using it.

Comment: Since the function has invalid syntax, it's not being defined, so submitting it just does normal form submission. Have you bothered to look at the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your example.

For one, you should always `return false;` or call `preventDefault()` on your form event (passed in via argument to your onsubmit handler. If you don't return false or preventDefault your page will reload. You are returning true in a few instances.

The other problem is that stuff like `document.myForm.csi.value` is not a thing. You should probably set ids on your input elements and use `document.getElementById()` to get at them, that or use a query selector (usually people use jQuery but you don't have to use that.').

The other thing is that ids should always be unique. You've got a couple that are shared.

Finally to get at a select you have look at selectedIndexed.

For the radio inputs you might want to iterate through those and see which is checked.

Comment: `document.myform.csi.value` is a thing. All the forms in a document are properties of `document`, and all the inputs in a form are properties of the form. This was the early way to access form inputs in Javascript, it's not common now.

Comment: @Barmar it's not a thing in his example. `csi` is in the JavaScript but not in the markup.

Comment: I updated my code if you would like to check it out... I am a slow learner (I have epilepsy) so as much definition would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you should checkout the JavaScript tutorials on CodeAcademy or read a book or something so you have an easier time. Check out http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript or look at some Wrox or Oreilly books.